# Django: path to static file is wrong in generated HTML

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have some javascript that I would like to run on a particular page of a Django site I am building. In the template I currently have:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='{% static "/home_page/github_repos.js" %}'></script>`

The HTML that is generated by this is:
`http://localhost:8000/home_page/github_repos.js`

The problem is that I have the javascript in `/static/home_page/`.

If I hardcode in the path as:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='static/home_page/github_repos.js'></script>`

Everything works fine.

However, I am getting odd behavior that I do not understand:

If, in the template I set the path like this: 
`<script type='text/javascript' src='{% static "static/home_page/github_repos.js" %}'></script>`

The HTML generate has a src attribute of `/static/static/home_page/github_repos.js`

The part that is really throwing me off is that if I do not put `/static/` at the front of the src when using the template tags (like the first example I give), `/static/` is not added, however, if I do add `/static/` at the front, it gets added. I need `/static/` added to the front of the src attribute, but only once.

Some relevant information:
My home_page app resolves to '/' as the url, so `localhost:8000/` gets you to the home page.

I have included`'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in my installed apps

Finally, `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Is this problem occurring because my home_page app resolves to the root address of `localhost:8000/`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because the path in the `static` tag should be *relative* to the static directory. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static):

> Uses the configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` storage to create the full URL for the given **relative path**

You're using an absolute path. Instead, you should use:

```
{% static "home_page/github_repos.js" %}
```

Note the omission of the leading forward slash.